# Is there an analog of `mpirun -n` for a function/subroutine?

Tags: c, mpi

I'd like to benchmark OMP and MPI. I already have a function which is properly implemented as a serial function, as a function using openmp, and as a function using MPI.

Now, I would like to benchmark the implementations and see how it scales with the number of threads.

I could do it by hand in the following way:
`$./my_serial`
which returns the average execution time for some computations,

then `$./my_OMP <number of threads>`, where I pass the number of threads to an expression `#pragma omp parallel for private(j) shared(a) num_threads(nthreads)` with `j` a running variable and `a` an array that contains `doubles`, which also returns the average execution time.

I automated the part that calls `my_OMP` with increasing number of threads. Now, I would like to implement something similar using a function that is based on MPI. Again, by hand I would do:

`$mpirun -np <number_of_threads> ./my_mpi`,

which would return me the average computation time and then I would increase the number of threads.

So, instead of calling `my_mpi` several times by hand and noting down the return value, I'd like to automate this, i.e. I'd like to have a loop that increases the number of threads and stores the return values in an array.
How can I implement that?

I thought about running the program once with `$mpirun -np MAX_NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_THREADS ./my_mpi` and then limiting the number of parallel threads to 1 for the serial and OMP part and increasing the limit of parallel threads in a loop for the actual MPI part, but I don't know how to to this.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how MPI works. MPI is process bases, so `mpirun -n 27 yourprogram` starts 27 instances of your executable, and they communicate through OS means. Thus there is no "serial part": each process executes every single statement in your source.

What you could do is

1. give your timed routine a communicator argument
2. make a series of increasing sized subcommunicators, and
3. call your timed routine with those subcommunicators.

Comment: Thank you very much, @victor-eijkhout! You didn't come across by an example code that does something similar by any chance?